# how to make a very smooth gradient between two close colors

Tags: gradient, photoshop

I have an image with black (#000000) background and beneath the background there is a layer with the color of (#141414).

I have cut the border of my image with "feather" 20px, but the gradient from #000000 to #141414 is not smooth and does not look good. How can I make a smooth transition between these two colors?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `Dither` in gradient settings to add some noise to the gradient to avoid [banding effect](http://www.iceflowstudios.com/2013/tips/smooth-gradients-in-photoshop-dithering/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the [Gradient Editor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/gradients.html):

[image]

[image]